# Why SSRS are date parameters invalid when from a selection but not when "default"?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a selection of SSRS report where the client has requested that there is a different reporting range for each schedule e.g. The daily schedule run Daily reporting on sales for the past day, the Weekly schedule to report on previous week etc. I am trying to use one "sales" report to do this and have different options for the "Start" date as a parameter that can be selected. I have set these up as "Available" values rather than a "Default" with the following:

Daily = `=DateAdd("D",-1,Today())`

Monthly = `=DateAdd("M",-1,Today())`

I have set up a scheduled for this report to run using the parameter and selected "Daily" but when this runs I get the following error message:

> The subscription contains parameter values that are not valid.

And then if I look at the subscription settings, the "Start" parameter is completely blank forcing me to select Daily or Monthly again. If I were to instead set it up as a *default* value using one of those parameter mappings then it works absolutely fine. Is there a way to have these optional parameters, or am I going to be forced to create different Daily/Weekly/Monthly reports each with their own *default* parameters for the start times.

Note: When I debug the report with those parameters it runs absolutely fine, the issue is with the scheduled versions not keeping the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to data-driven subscriptions with your SSRS version, you can pass in multiple dates, emails, etc. This allows you to send out different versions of the report in one subscription.

Another option would be to add another parameter with the Daily/Weekly/Monthly option. Then have the default date use this parameter value to determine the date value. Then you could have 3 subscriptions on the same report each with their own interval selected.

I hope one of these options will work for you.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using this method but it didn't seem to work. I set up a new parameter called StartDEFAULT and set that to use whatever parameter was chosen in the main "Start" parameter. The SQL code was set to subsequently use the new StartDEFAULT parameter but the scheduled failed for the same reason. It appears when the parameter is chosen from the drop-down box it doesn't like it at all.